# How can I test that I am correctly setting a new ntp server?

Tags: ubuntu, ntp

I have a config script that is configuring the ntp server of a machine (which is running Ubuntu 14.04) by stripping lines matching `^server .*` from `/etc/ntp.conf` and adding a new line `server new.ntp.address`. Now I want to test that this change is valid and working.

My initial thought was to have `new.ntp.address` be my desktop (which is running `ntp`) and set my desktop's time to something new, but after some reading I noticed that ntp will reject all but slight changes to the current time. How can I verify that my change to the ntp server config is correct and working?

Per [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ntp), I ran `sudo ntpdate -dv <my ip address>` from the client machine I was configuring. The output showed it did not find an npt server because the strata was too high:

```
$ sudo ntpdate -dv 192.168.12.125
23 Sep 16:30:37 ntpdate[26673]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Wed Oct  9 19:08:07 UTC 2013 (1)
Looking for host 192.168.12.125 and service ntp
host found : 192.168.12.125
transmit(192.168.12.125)
receive(192.168.12.125)
transmit(192.168.12.125)
receive(192.168.12.125)
transmit(192.168.12.125)
receive(192.168.12.125)
transmit(192.168.12.125)
receive(192.168.12.125)
192.168.12.125: Server dropped: strata too high
server 192.168.12.125, port 123
stratum 16, precision -23, leap 11, trust 000
refid [192.168.12.125], delay 0.02586, dispersion 0.00011
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Sun, Dec 31 1899 16:00:00.000
originate timestamp: d7cc8124.166c9d3f  Tue, Sep 23 2014 16:30:44.087
transmit timestamp:  d7cc8124.16e4ba7a  Tue, Sep 23 2014 16:30:44.089
filter delay:  0.02586  0.02736  0.02599  0.02586 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: -0.00204 -0.00129 -0.00211 -0.00204
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.02586, dispersion 0.00011
offset -0.002042

23 Sep 16:30:44 ntpdate[26673]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

EDIT1: I used [these instructions](http://en.linuxreviews.org/NTP_-_Howto_make_the_clock_show_the_correct_time) to fudge the strata on my desktop, which is acting as the ntp server. Now, when I run `sudo ntpdate <my ntp server address>` from the client machine it updates its time (in my case I had to set a fairly small but noticeable change to the server time to witness this working, about 55 seconds skew is what I introduced on my desktop). However, when I start `ntp` on the client again and try to see it automatically pick up the changes, I'm unable to see it adjust the clock time even though I waited several minutes after starting `ntp` (it seemed from googling that the standard polling frequency is 60 seconds). How can I troubleshoot this?

EDIT2: Eventually the clocks did synchronize, but it took significantly longer than a minute. I think this suffices to verify my experiment, but I'm still interested in if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The commands `ntpstat` and `ntpq -p` off-hand

(from mobile so without sample output for now)